# When is $\dim(V^*)\gt \dim(V)$ $?$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$  be  an  infinite dimensional vector space  over  $\mathbb Z_2$  with  countably  infinite  basis  $\{e_1,e_2,e_3,.....,e_n,....\}$ and  write  $$V=S+T$$  s.t. $$S=\langle e_1 \rangle$$  and  $$T=\langle e_2,e_3,...,e_n,...\rangle.$$

Then $$T^*=S^0$$  is  easy  to  see but  how  can  I  prove  that $$T^*\cong V^*$$ and  $$\dim(V^*)\gt \dim(V)\ ?$$

Clearly $V^*$  has  a  function  that  takes  $e_1$  to  $1$  and  the  rest  to  $0$  which  is  not   in  $T^*$ .  Although  that  is  not  going  to  stop  isomorphism  as  the  sets  are  infinite.

But  how  to  prove  $?$

Comment: What does $S^0$ mean here?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom :  It  means  the  annihilator  of  $S$

Comment: then the equality isn't correct.  Yes, $T^* \cong S^0$, but the spaces aren't "equal", so far as I can tell.

Answer (score 3):

To show $T^*\cong V^*$: think about the map $T\rightarrow V$ generated by $e_{i+1}\mapsto e_i$ . . .

To show $\dim(V^*)>\dim(V)$, note that $V$ is countable, so it's enough to show that $V^*$ is uncountable. Can you think of an injection from $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ to $V^*$? (HINT: identify $\mathbb{N}$ with $\{e_1, e_2, e_3, . . .\}$ . . .)

Comment: $e_{i+1}\mapsto e_i$  means  $e_2\mapsto e_1$  but  $e_1\mapsto ??$ . This  function  is  not  defined  on  all  of  $V$ . So $?$

Comment: But it is defined on all of $T$ . . . As a map from $T$ to $V$, what does it do? What does this tell you about the associated dual spaces?

Comment: As a  map  from  $T$  to  $V$  $?$ In  your  answer  you  said  it  was  a  map  from  $V$  to  $T$  . I'm confused  now .

Comment: @user118494 Whoops, that's my bad, fixed. (I was torn between writing the map from $T$ to $V$, or writing the map $e_i\mapsto e_{i+1}$. Either would be fine; combining both yields *stupid*.)

Comment: For  any  subset $\{n_1,...,n_k\}$  of  $\mathbb N$ ,  choose  the  map  $f$ from  $V^*$  such  that  $f$  takes  $e_{n_1},...,e_{n_k}$  to  $1$'s  and  others  to  $0$  ,. Right  ?

Comment: @user118494 Sure - but note that you don't need the subset to be *finite*! That construction works for arbitrary subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, of which there are uncountably many.

Answer (score 3):

To address the question in your title: note that for any sequence $(x_n) \subset \{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}$, we can define an element of $V^*$ by
$$
e_n \mapsto x_n
$$
And all such elements are linearly independent.

As such, $V^*$ has dimension $2^{|\Bbb N|}$, which is uncountable and therefore greater than $\dim(V) = |\Bbb N|$.

**Point to consider:** why is $\sum x_n e_n$ **not** generally an element of $V$?